# How to remove a comma that separates the values from an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have this code in JS:

```
var array = ['one', 'two'];
```

And each time I want to display the array, it is displayed with like this:

```
one,two
```

Now my question is, is there any way to remove that nasty comma?

Comment: You want it displayed as "onetwo"? Or... "one two" with a space

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to display the array?

Comment: To remove a coma, you'd better visit a medic. Thank god, it turned out to be a comma!

Comment: that is funny:)))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To display them next to each other, you can use join. `array.join(' ');`

Comment: Hi, I want it to be displayed like this

    'one two' with a space, thank you

Comment: join can take any string as a parameter which it will use to delimit values in the array. e.g. `['one', 'two', 'three'].join(' SHIZZAM! ');` will give you `one SHIZZAM! two SHIZZAM! three`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help guys I cannot say how much you helped me! And god you are so quick! For less than 5 minutes!!!!

One last stupid question tho - how can I vote the comments here, please?

Comment: @Stefany - you may not be able to vote because you are just starting on Stack Overflow... although you can accept this answer as the correct one, thats reward enough ;)

Comment: Oh thank you Tim, that was very kind of you to explain. I rewarded you already :D

Answer (score 1):

You could use the replace method of the string object:

```
array.toString().replace(',',' ')
```

Comment: and what if the indexes have commas in them? This would break. Better to use `join()`.

Comment: He asked how to remove the comma, not how to join the elements of an array.  I'd use join() in this case too :)

Comment: It will not work
suppose Array selIdss has values like 1,2,3  but replace will only remove first comma
output will be  1;2,3